# React-Typescript: How do I type a default prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Let's say I have this component class:

```
interface SomeComponentProps {
  someOptionalProperty?: string;
}
interface SomeComponentState { /* ... */ }

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<SomeComponentProps, SomeComponentState> {
  static defaultProps = {
    someOptionalProp = 'some default value',
  }

  method() {
    const shouldNotBeOptional = this.props.someOptionalProp;
  }
}
```

How can I assert that `this.props.someOptionalProp` is not undefined within the class but is also optional when trying to using the component?

What I've been doing is just ignoring `defaultProps` altogether by creating getters that

```
return `this.props.someOptionalProp || 'the default value'`;
```

but I'd like to use `defaultProps` because my team uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has been discussed and resolved in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24422#issuecomment-395168742). Now you simply can do that:

```
interface Props {
  thing: string; // note: not optional within class, but is optional when writing due to the default
}

class Thing extends React.Component<Props> {
   static defaultProps = {
      thing: 'hello'
   }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.thing) // strict type from `Props`
    // ...
 }
}
// ..
<Thing /> // works, thanks to `defaultProps`
```

It works for me in Typescript 3.1.6 and React 16.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible as it stands with TS 2.8.3, there are some issues open about it already

On react types: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11640

On the TS repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23812

Best you can achieve currently I believe is by using the `!` operator to tell the compiler that you know something can't be null

```
const shouldNotBeOptional = this.props.someOptionalProp!;
```

Comment: thanks for the links. maybe with the new conditional types, it's possible to write better typings. I'll experiment and maybe do a pull request if what I find is good enough

Comment: Mkay .. guess I didn't know it was impossible, you can't do it in a single type but I think my approach gets it pretty close..

Answer (score 1):

You could use a higher order component (HOC) that will just change the type of the props to be optional where they are present in `defaultProps`

```
interface SomeComponentProps {
    required: string;
    someOptionalProperty: string;
    trulyOptional?: string;
}
interface SomeComponentState { /* ... */ }

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<SomeComponentProps, SomeComponentState> {
    static defaultProps = {
        someOptionalProperty : 'some default value',
    }

    method() {
        const shouldNotBeOptional = this.props.someOptionalProperty;
    }
}

type SameTypeOrCustomError<T1, T2> = T1 extends T2 ? T2 extends T1 ? T1 : "Error Different Types": "Error Different Types";
type FilterOptional<T> = Exclude<{ [P in keyof T]: undefined extends T[P]? P: never }[keyof T], undefined>;

type d = FilterOptional<SomeComponentProps>
type PropsWithDefault<TProps extends TDefaults, TDefaults> = 
    { [P in Exclude<keyof TProps, keyof TDefaults | FilterOptional<TProps>>]: TProps[P] } &
    { [P in keyof TDefaults | FilterOptional<TProps>]?: TProps[P] }; 

type ReactProps<T> = T extends React.Component<infer Props, any> ? Props: never;
type ReactState<T> = T extends React.Component<any, infer TState> ? TState: never;
type ChangeReactProps<TComponent extends React.Component<any, any>, TNewProps> = {
    new (props: TNewProps, context?: any) : React.Component<TNewProps, ReactState<TComponent>>
};

function withDefaults<T extends { new (...args: any[]) : any, defaultProps: Partial<ReactProps<InstanceType<T>>> }>(ctor: T) 
    : ChangeReactProps<InstanceType<T>, PropsWithDefault<ReactProps<InstanceType<T>>, T['defaultProps']>>  {
    return ctor; // we just chage type, we can return the same class 
}


const SomeComponent2 = withDefaults(SomeComponent);

let d = <SomeComponent2  required=""  /> //ok 
let x = <SomeComponent2  required="" trulyOptional="" /> //ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a higher order component with Typescript 2.8 in my codebase:

```typescript
const withDefaultProps = <P extends object, DP extends Partial<P>>(
  defaultProps: DP,
  component: React.ComponentType<P>
) => {
  type ActualProps = Partial<DP> & Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof DP>>
  component.defaultProps = defaultProps
  return component as React.ComponentType<ActualProps>
}

interface IComponentProps {
  someOptionalProp: string
}

class SomeComponent extends React.Component<IComponentProps, {}> {
  method() {
    // this is always defined
    const shouldNotBeOptional = this.props.someOptionalProp;
  }
}

// when using this like <SomeComponent />, someOptionalProp is optional
export default withDefaultProps(
  { someOptionalProp: 'defaultValue' },
  SomeComponent
)
```